# Hive table partition by year month and day query

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Hi I am using a hive table partitioned by 3 columns (year, month and day). I have the data in below format.

```
/table1/year=2024/month=1/day=20/file1
/table1/year=2024/month=1/day=16/file1
/table1/year=2024/month=1/day=9/file1
```

Need help to write a select query to get all the records from the latest year, month and day partition dynamically.

Below is the query with hard coded values and I need dynamic query for the same. Thanks

Select * from table1 where year=2024 and month=1 and day=20;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate those columns using year(), month(), and day() functions on sysdate()

```
Select * from table1 where year=year(current_timestamp()) and month = month(current_timestamp())  and day=day(current_timestamp());
```

if you dont know what is max partition in the table, you need to use below SQL -

```
select * from table1  
join (
select max(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( concat(day, case when length(month)=1,'0','' end,month,year)  , 'ddMMyyyy'))) as dt from table1) maxdt on 
from_unixtime(unix_timestamp( concat(day, case when length(month)=1,'0','' end,month,year)  , 'ddMMyyyy')) = maxdt.dt
```

the subquery `maxdt` in inner join returns max date of the partitions.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. As mentioned the data format, the year, month and date can be anything not the current date. I just need to get the latest partitions available in the table dynamically. Please suggest thanks in advance